# Auto-Detect character encoding in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, character-encoding, iconv

I am looking for a method to accurately detect character encoding of SRT subtitle files, for given (user-selected) language. I am currently using jschardet library for detection, which unfortunately gets it wrong very often.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var jschardet = require("jschardet");
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

var loadFile = function(path, langCode){
    var content = fs.readFileSync(path);
    var encoding = jschardet.detect(content).encoding.toLowerCase();
    return iconv.decode(content, encoding);
};
```

(added this just in case there's something wrong with my code)

Is there anything more accurate than jschardet? Perhaps something that also receives language as an argument? I guess this info could improve accuracy a lot, but I'm not familiar with any libraries that receive language as an argument.

Comment: First of all, library recommendations are off-topic on SO. But that aside - if you know the language, there are only a couple of possibilities. I'd guess one of ex-Yugoslav ones, based on your name, so: Windows-1250, UTF-8, UTF-16; for Cyrillic, Windows-1251; and YUSCII, CP852 (and CP866) if you're lagging a couple of decades. A couple more if you also want to check for Apple ones for MacOS before OSX. But realistically, only 2-3. Just check for presence of the byte sequences corresponding to the ten special letters, and if you find them in significant quantities you know your encoding.